# Debian 10 buster apt upgrade failed

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade

During apt-get upgrade I got the message:

```
Configurazione di linux-headers-4.19.0-17-686-pae (4.19.194-3)...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.0-17-686-pae (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/open-vm-tools/9.4.6/build/make.log for more information.
Configurazione di linux-headers-4.19.0-17-686 (4.19.194-3)...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.0-17-686 (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/open-vm-tools/9.4.6/build/make.log for more information.
```

three times, but also continue apparently well: this occurred during last upgradings, have I to get worried about?
Thanks
Renato I can attach the make.log file